# Open social date format

Tags: datetime

I'm working on a Open Social (Drupal 8) implementation. When adding an event you can submit the begin & end date. Is there any way to change the date format in these forms? I went through the whole system, found a lot of date format settings, non of them had any influence on this form.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have the Field UI module enabled.

If you go to `Structure > Content Types > Event > Manage form display` (`admin/structure/types/manage/event/form-display`) then you can change the form widget that is used there.

The `Date and time` widget which is the default has no configuration available. However, you can also use the `select list` widget which allows you to specify `Date part order` and `Time type`.

Comment: It's a shame the widget has no configuration available. The select list works, so let's use that for now. :)